# Inconsistent behavior between maps and sets in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Steve Losh [posted](https://twitter.com/stevelosh/status/266769468783460352) [the following Clojure snippet](https://gist.github.com/4043824):

```
; Integers and Longs are equal.
(= (Integer. 1) (Long. 1))
true

; Even negative ones.
(= (Integer. -1) (Long. -1))
true

; When you use them as keys in maps, the maps are still equal.
(= {(Integer. 1) :foo} {(Long. 1) :foo})
true

(= {(Integer. -1) :foo} {(Long. -1) :foo})
true

; When you use positive numbers as keys to sets, they're also equal.
(= #{(Integer. 1)} #{(Long. 1)})
true

; But negative ones aren't. But only in sets. Maps are fine. lol.
(= #{(Integer. -1)} #{(Long. -1)})
false
```

What is the reason for this behavior? Is it considered a defect or is there a "formal logic" / set theory reason why `(Integer. -1)` not equaling `(Long. -1)` in a persistent set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bug in Clojure: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1106

*text to satisfy stack overflow's stupid character limit goes here*